# Total score fell down

Tags: support, reputation

[My](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123111/kirill-v-lyadvinsky) total score on SO on [C++ tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=c%2b%2b&sort=stats&pagesize=15) fell down from about 1100+ to 985 in last 12 hours. That incident changed my position from 16-th to 19-th place in C++ tag. At the same time my reputation wasn't changed. What's wrong with it?

Comment: aww.  score fall down go boom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that it was [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028) being made CW (along with all its answers). Although reputation gained before a post is made CW is generally retained, my guess is that that doesn't apply to votes for the stats pages.

Your answer on that post had 155 votes, so "losing" that answer would certainly affect your stats on the C++ tag significantly.

Comment: Good guess. The question is should stats pages keep votes that gained before a post was made CW. Or it is by design?

Comment: @jia3ep: I suspect it's more for convenience of doing a query, to be honest. I would guess it's probably a pretty hefty query already.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a re-tag may have happened, where some of the questions were relieved of the `[C++]` tag in favor of something else.

I'm not sure how to verify this hypothesis, but it explains your observations.  Offhand I can't think of another hypothesis that fits.

Comment: Such massive retagging should affect other answerers.

Comment: how do you know it didn't?  your observations are a) your particular scores pre- and post- (and note you just have a range for pre-); and b) your ranking pre- and post-.  do you really have the other top 20 users' pre- scores?  do you know for sure yours is the only position that changed (excepting those who rose due to your fall)?